# How to access dynamic array and get key-value pairs using ng-repeat

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to retrieve data from json object for ionic mobile application. But the problem is inside that object has an array this array includes a set of objects. I need to get the key and value pairs from those set of objects, I tried following code to achieve that.

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="form in forms">
    <ion-item>
        {{form.Form_Group_Name}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label colone-input" ng-repeat="(key, value) in form.items">
            <span class="input-label">{{key}}</span>
            <input type="text" value="{{ value }}" placeholder="First name">
        </label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

This is working, but as a key it shows the index of the array (see the following images). Array size can be dynamically changed so then can't use index no to access this. I need to go inside the array and access the object to get key and value.

here is the sample of my json object

[image]

result is like this :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: items is an array. You iterate over an array the way you're already doing it in your first ng-repeat: `ng-repeat="item in form.items"`. Then you would have to iterate over the key/value pairs of each item. But it seems each item has a single one. So, first, that is a huge smell: the backend API has a really strange way of returning data, so I would try to fix the backend instead, so that it just returns a single object with title, first name, gender, etc. Otherwise, I would fix thet in the controller, to make the job of the view easier. Merge all these items in a single object.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="form in forms['Form Groups']">
    <ion-item >
        {{form['Form Group Name']}}
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label colone-input" ng-repeat="item in form.items">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in item">
                <span class="input-label">{{key}}</span>
                <input type="text" value="{{ value }}" placeholder="value">
            </div>
        </label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

As you can see here, I added `<div>` and inside that `<div>` iterate the item array. The item array includes all the data form json object and then I request key and value from array when the time of the iteration.